# Métodos básicos en C++

Tags: c++, método

Estaba investigando cómo declarar funciones, pero me atoré tratando de declarar una que imprimiera una serie de lineas dentro de una estructura. Me preguntaba cómo era posible hacerlo.

Aquí simplifiqué todo mi programa, pero básicamente eso es lo que necesito que haga.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Dato {
int a;
int b;
}Prueba[2];

Void MuestraLista() {
    std::cout << "1) Numero de empleado: " << Prueba[1].a << "\tSueldo: " << 
    Prueba[1].b; 
    std::cout << "\n2) Numero de empleado: " << Prueba[2].a << "\tSueldo: " 
    << Prueba[2].b; 
    }

int main(){
Prueba[1].a=500;
Prueba[1].b=300;
Prueba[2].a=600;
Prueba[2].b=100;

MuestraLista();

system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Void no está definido.

Comment: Has puesto `Void` **con mayúscula**. Es `void`, todo en minúsculas.

Comment: Whoops, typo. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente es el mal manejo de tu array.

Cuando se **CREA** un nuevo **ARRAY** de tamaño **N**, este debe de ser recorrido desde `0 hasta N-1`, esto para todos los lenguajes, o por lo menos para c, c++, java, javascript, c#, python, VB, php, entre muchos otros.

Entonces, cuando tu haces `Prueba[2]`, estas apuntado a un indice inexistente, provocando un error de memoria.

> Vale decir que tu problema se soluciona haciendo que todos los `Prueba[1]` cambien a `Prueba[0]` y que `Prueba[2]` cambien a `Prueba[1]`.

Espero Haber ayudado.